# Ajax function gives Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: ajax

This function works fine as long im on the same page where the search div `imagesearch` is.
If im on another site on the website, ill get the error

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

The console point put row 27, that's where the if statement start `if(q.length.`.

Cant really find out whats the problem. Any ideas ?

```
function reloadSearch() {
       if (!isLoading) {
          var q = $('#imagesearch').val();
          if (q.length >= 2) {
             isLoading = true;
             $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'core/flickr.php',
                data: 'search=' + q,
                dataType: 'html',
                beforeSend: function () {
                   $('#imageresult').html(
                      '<img src="img/loading45.gif" alt="loading..." />');
                   if (!q[0]) {
                      $('#imageresult').html(
                         '');
                      return false;
                   }
                },
                success: function (response) {
                   $('#imageresult').html(
                      response);
                }
             });
             // enforce the delay
             setTimeout(function () {
                isLoading = false;
                if (isDirty) {
                   isDirty = false;
                   reloadSearch();
                }
             }, delay);
          }
       }
    };

    var delay = 1000;
    var isLoading = false;
    var isDirty = false;

        $(document).ready(function () {
           reloadSearch();
           $('#imagesearch').keyup(function () {
              isDirty = true;
              reloadSearch();
           });
        });
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log($("#imagesearch").val())`? I don't suppose it's `undefined`? ;)

Comment: @MartyWallace Well, yes if im on another page, if im on the same where the div is. it prints out my entered keys.

Comment: So from there work backwards. Most likely is that your selector is wrong, or you haven't added the ID that you think you have to the element you're trying to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
if (q.length >= 2) {
```

to

```
if (q !== undefined && q.length >= 2) {
```

this will stop the can't read value from undefined...If you code in .Net this is similar to the null reference exception.

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thanks